# Read from a .txt file and display it

Tags: python

I want to be able to have a .txt file with some text in it and have my program be able to read it and display it. How would I do this?

It just needs to be as simple as displaying it on the screen. No other code. Then I can just input it into my program! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(your_file_name_path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Why do you print line after line?

Comment: @Reznik It is a better way as suppose the file has a poem.

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer :)

```py
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

If you want the lines seperete you can go with:

```py
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: @ThomasKeig you welcome, mark it as correct answer so other people can see it and use it :)

Comment: got a problem. If my .txt file has multiple lines it doesn't print the lines individually. It prints them all at once?

Comment: Thanks. Marked you answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

[Manual from docs python.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

What u searching is open function.

```
with open('workfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Why do you print line after line?

Comment: @Reznik it's just copy of python.docs `open()` method.

Comment: well thats redundent, in this case he just want to print out all the file content

Comment: @Reznik this way is printing all the content as well. Through the loop, but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a built-in `open` function. Use it like this:

```py
with open('filepath', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
```

Alternatively:

```
f = open('filepath', 'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

I recommend reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp) as well.

Comment: You didnt close the fd after using it in the second answer

Comment: you dont need to close the fd inside a context manager, its all the point of the context manager :)